# Spring Integration - setting upper limit on sending messages

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am writing a mail service that replies to incoming messages and I'd like to set up a limit - max 10 sent messages/hour. It should reset at full hour too.

Is it possible in Spring Integration? I read about Task Scheduling in Spring docs, but I'm not sure if that matches my case. I guess I could set up a CronTrigger that sends the messages at a fixed rate, but that doesn't sound like it does what I actually want to achieve.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you go right way though.

You configure a `QeueueChannel` and `PollingConsumer` (`@ServiceActivator` with the `@Poller`). You definitely can go the cron trigger there:

```
/**
 * @return The cron expression to create the {@link CronTrigger}.
 * Can be specified as 'property placeholder', e.g. {@code ${poller.cron}}.
 */
String cron() default "";
```

And your requirement about `max 10 sent messages/hour` ca be achieved with the:

```
/**
 * @return The maximum number of messages to receive for each poll.
 * Can be specified as 'property placeholder', e.g. {@code ${poller.maxMessagesPerPoll}}.
 * Defaults to -1 (infinity) for polling consumers and 1 for polling inbound channel adapters.
 */
String maxMessagesPerPoll() default "";
```

So, when the task is performed by the scheduler according the configured cron time, only configured `maxMessagesPerPoll` will be pulled from the `QeueueChannel` and sent downstream for processing (sending emails).

See more info in the https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#polling-consumer and seek for the `Important: Poller Configuration` paragraph.

Comment: `Polling Consumers allow Spring Integration components to actively poll for Messages, rather than to process Messages in an event-driven manner.` I am using IMAP idle :( thank you for answering though!

Comment: ??? The IMAP Idle isn't related to the sending part. Spring Integration via its loosely coupled approach with the `MessageChannel` abstraction allows you to build the flow any complexity. You asked about `10 messages per hour`, I answered you how to do that. The doc I'm pointing might mislead a bit, agree, but the same `poller` rules are applied to the Polling Consumer on the `QueueChannel`. I think you need to read more about Spring Integration to make yourself familiar about principles and concepts. But again: the IMAP idle doesn't send emails, it receives them. That's different story

Comment: you're right - I am sorry, I was kind of confused by the description of Polling Consumer and the problems I am having with current code right now - I thought you couldn't pair IMAP idle and Polling Consumer together for some reason. but that's irrelevant, thank you for the effort, tagging your answer as accepted

Comment: actually, doesnt that solution send these 10 messages once per hour?